# Using PayPal Authorization & Capture with Reference Transactions

Tags: paypal, reference, transactions, express-checkout

For a new project we are looking for a payment system that allows a single user authorization for charging their credit card for a service multiple times over a long period of time - pay as you go. We would also like to secure appropriate amount of money just in case when the service usage is started and actually charge it after usage is completed and the exact amount of money to charge is known. This means we want to use [Reference Transactions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-refTrans-SetEC-DoRefTrans-curl-etc/) with each pre-authorized charge using [PayPal's Authorization & Capture mechanism](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/admin/auth-capture/). So the question is:

**Can PayPal Authorization & Capture mechanism be used together with Reference Transactions?**

Can we:

- obtain customer authorization to charge them in the future,
- use the authorization to secure funds,
- charge a part of the previously authorized funds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/?mark=reference , you can use PAYMENTACTION=Authorization in DoReferenceTransaction API.

Comment: Yeah, this will work. Too bad we won't be able to use it right away in practice - as a fresh project we are not eligible for Reference Transactions for now.

Comment: Yes, you can apply reference transaction again after your business grows  to a certain level.